# External system is not responding in maximo, not able to track the event in logs also

Tags: transactions, maximo, inbound

In maximo v7.5 I am trying to upload data using external systems > enterprise services but the new data is not reflected in maximo , no errors either in logs or in file management or no messages stucked in queues. Infact , inbound transaction successful message is appearing each time when i tried.

Comment: Need help! Urgent issue .

Comment: Nothing immediately comes to mind on so little information. My best guess would be that you aren't actually matching the keys of existing records for Maximo to know what to update and so it just passes through. Knowing what service you are uploading to, what objects are in it (if it isn't out of the box) and what data is in your file (all of it, including the header information) would go a long way to allowing others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your uploads to the queue are successful, but the Maximo mechanisms for pulling from whichever queue you are uploading to are disabled.

- If Use Continuous Queue is checked for the Enterprise Service you are loading to, then you need to check that your Message Driven Bean (MDB) is enabled. (Some web searches should help with that.)
- If Use Continuous Queue is NOT checked, then check that the SEQQIN instance of the JMSQSEQCONSUMER cron task is enabled in Cron Task Setup.
- And if both of those things check out, make sure Admin Mode is OFF.

Comment: If the cron tasks are off though (or disabled because of Admin Mode), wouldn't the messages just sit in the queue?

Comment: Yes. They wouldn't fail into Message Reprocessing or cause other errors. They would just sit there. And adding to the queue through the UI would still work just fine, as @devn_ns described.

Comment: In fact, the OP could go into their WebSphere or WebLogic console (whichever they're using) and see how many messages are waiting in the queue for processing. And after importing again, I bet that number will go up.

Comment: Part of his question does say there are no messages stuck in the queues.

Comment: @dex good point. I missed that the first time around. Maybe this answer will just get "useful" points, then. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Look on the Enterprise Service to see if there's a SKIP rule with no conditions.